# Enable CPLEX to use disk instead of memory

Tags: java, cplex

I have an optimization project coded in Java using CPLEX. When the size of the input data grows, I am getting out of memory errors etc. What can I do to make CPLEX use disk and reduce the memory usage of CPLEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with the WorkMem (CPX_PARAM_WORKMEM), NodeFileInd (CPX_PARAM_NODEFILEIND), TreLim (CPX_PARAM_TRELIM), and WorkDir (CPX_PARAM_WORKDIR) parameters.

These have a major impact on memory management.